# tooltip doesn't turnup on hover in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/CYJAk/13/

have a look at it, the tooltip doesn't show at all.
i donno if tooltip dataFormat is being over-ridden by some other function.
and also
the date in x-axis when zoomed in doesn't show minutes, what should i do for that?

Comment: I addressed your first question below, for the second, I see minutes.  At "Day" I see 21:00, 00:00, etc...

Comment: sorry, i wrote it in a wrong way, 
actually i want x-axis to show the time with minutes , not just :00 always as a boundary, it should be like http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/intraday which shows with interval of 30 secs. 
is it because series type is not 'candlestick' ?

Anyway, below answer helped me to show minutes in tool-tip it is enough i think.
If u found a solution for tht , reply me 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under firefox, I can see that your javascript error in your tooltip formatter is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

This seems contrary to the [docs](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/ref/#tooltip--formatter) (perhaps because it is not shared?).  I find that using

```
this.points[0].series.name
```

fixes this.  Note, you'll also have to change your this.y to something similar `this.points[0].y` for that to work.

Answer (score 1):

From a completely different perspective -
I was also having problems with Highcharts tooltips using Chrome on my Ultrabook. This problem was not occurring in IE or FireFox.

I was not using shared series, so the solution above did not apply.

Turns out the problem is that Chrome recognizes the Ultrabook has a touchscreen, and enables the touch events. Highcharts (v2.2.5) does not enable the 'mouseover' event for devices that support touch, but instead enables the 'touchstart' event. As the 'touchstart' was not occuring when my mouse hovered over the icon, the tooltip never appeared.

This is the line in Highcharts that adds the handler based on the device type:

```
.on(hasTouch ? 'touchstart' : 'mouseover', function (e) {
    series.onMouseOver();
    if (e.target._i !== UNDEFINED) { // undefined on graph in scatterchart
        points[e.target._i].onMouseOver();
    }
})
```

Thus, it would probably work to explicitly add a 'mouseover' handler and trigger a 'touchstart' in these cases.

Highcharts checks for the existence of ontouchstart to determine touch-enabled devices:

```
hasTouch = doc.documentElement.ontouchstart !== UNDEFINED,
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
formatter: function() {
    var point = this.points[0],
        x = point.x,
        y = point.y,
        seriesName = point.series.name;

    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%A,%b %e,%Y, %H:%M', x) +'<br/> '+'<strong>'+ seriesName +'</strong>'+ y;
}
```

I have been using Highcharts a lot but have never used Highstock but like [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8331609/738746) said this goes against the docs. Looks like a bug.